# Как в laravel изменить путь на авторизацию и при этом передать параметр?

Tags: laravel-5.8

Только начал изучать фреймворк Laravel и столкнулся с задачей, ответ на которую пока нигде не нашёл. Самостоятельно не смог решить. Прошу помочь разобраться.

**Версия**

Laravel Framework 6.10.1

**Задача**

Изменить путь на страницы авторизации и добавить в адрес параметр.

**Описание**

После выполнения команд

- composer require laravel/ui
- php artisan ui vue
- php artisan ui:auth

... получаем шаблоны, которые расположены в **resources/views/auth** и в **resources/views/layouts**

Теперь, чтобы попасть на страницу входа в адресной строке вводим адрес

localhost/login

Это адрес по умолчанию. Как его изменить таким образом, чтобы обеспечить мультиязычность сайта?

Адрес должен быть такого вида:

- localhost/**ru**/login
- localhost/**en**/login
- ... и т. д.

В файле **routes\web.php** после выполнения команд выше, изначально прописано:

```
Auth::routes();
```

Для переопределения маршрутов нашёл в интернете вариант, как в листинге ниже. Если сейчас изменить адрес для входа в систему, то получится перейти на страницу.

```
// Login
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function() {
    Route::get('/en/login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm']);
    Route::post('/en/login', ['as' => 'login.post', 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@login']);
    Route::post('/en/logout', ['as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@logout']);
});
// Registration Routes...
    Route::get('register', ['as' => 'register', 'uses' => 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm']);
    Route::post('register', ['as' => 'register.post', 'uses' => 'Auth\RegisterController@register']);

// Password Reset Routes...
    Route::get('password/reset', ['as' => 'password.reset', 'uses' => 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm']);
    Route::post('password/email', ['as' => 'password.email', 'uses' => 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail']);
    Route::get('password/reset/{token}', ['as' => 'password.reset.token', 'uses' => 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm']);
    Route::post('password/reset', ['as' => 'password.reset.post', 'uses' => 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset']);
```

Но, так как нужно передавать разные значения, то первая часть адреса должна передавать параметром:

```
'/{lang}/login'
```

Но при таком варианте получаю ошибку:

```
LOG.error: Missing required parameters for [Route: login] [URI: {url_lang}/login]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\poligon.local\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php) {"exception":{}}
```

Какие изменения нужно внести, чтобы решить эту задачу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для описанной задачи меня полностью устроило решение показанное в этом видео: https://youtu.be/_BsHyHc9NqE

Answer (score 1):

Добавить префикс

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => '{lang?}',
], function () {
    Auth::routes();
});
```

И добавить смену языка в `RouteServiceProvider::boot()`

```
Route::pattern('lang', 'en|ru|lv');

Route::matched(function (RouteMatched $event) {
    app()->setLocale($event->route->parameter('lang'));
});
```

Вот похожие темы:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/optional-language-for-all-routes

https://laraveldaily.com/multi-language-routes-and-locales-with-auth/

Comment: Спасибо, потестирую. Я пока воспользовался вот этим вариантом: https://youtu.be/_BsHyHc9NqE